# header expire on javascript files not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, header, mod-expires

I can't get the expire header on JS files to work properly.. It works fine on eg CSS files!?

Could anybody tell me what Im doing wrong? :(

## htaccess

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType image/gif A29030400
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A29030400
ExpiresByType image/png A29030400
ExpiresByType text/css A29030400
ExpiresByType text/javascript A29030400
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A29030400
```

## header on CSS file

```
Cache-Control   max-age=29030400
Connection  Keep-Alive
Date    Sun, 14 Oct 2012 12:06:45 GMT
Etag    "be-4cbcf2ad48b40"
Expires Sun, 15 Sep 2013 12:06:45 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=97
Server  Apache/2.4.2 (Win64) PHP/5.4.3
```

## header on JS file

```
Cache-Control   max-age=0
Connection  Keep-Alive
Date    Sun, 14 Oct 2012 12:06:45 GMT
Etag    "1ad-4cc00d069f493"
Expires Sun, 14 Oct 2012 12:06:45 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=99
Server  Apache/2.4.2 (Win64) PHP/5.4.3
```

Comment: As a test, are the values in the htaccess file those actually being shown in the header for the CSS? EG: if you change the A29030400 to something else, do you see that reflected in the served CSS header?

Also, as another test, what happens if you try formatting the htaccess in a different way: `...
ExpiresByType text/css A29030400

<filesMatch "\.(js)$">
ExpiresDefault A29030400
</filesMatch>` ?

Comment: add an answer.. the reg exp solution with filesMatch works! :D

Comment: Glad it helped, answer added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try wrapping an `ExpiresDefault` in a `<filesMatch` tag instead of using `ExpiresByType` :

```
<filesMatch "\.(js)$"> 
    ExpiresDefault A29030400 
</filesMatch>
```

Answer (score 9):

(can't comment yet...)
I run the following settings and it works.

```
ExpiresByType text/js "access plus 1 years"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 years"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 years"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 years"
```

Should work

Cheers
Robin

Answer (score 1):

You might need to activate the Expires module from inside your Apache host configuration.

In my case, I added

```
  ExpiresActive On
```

right before the first `ExpiresByType` directive and it started working instantly (after an Apache reload).

I'm not sure why this needs to be explicitly enabled. On other servers it used to work as soon as I enabled the mod with `a2enmod` (maybe with Apache 2.2, but I can't find a clear pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Old question but here's what I learned:

Press **F12** in your browser (I'm using Chrome) and go to the "**Network**" tab and look for the javascript that's not getting cached. Look for the **header information** there (via a "Headers" tab, for example) and look at the "**content-type**" in the response header information.

In my case it was "**application/javascript**", which I hadn't defined specifically in my `.htaccess`. Once I added that line:

```
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 2419200 seconds"
```

Then javascript was getting cached as expected.